# Erro com o ícone, vibração e som na notificação

Tags: android, firebase, android-notification

Eu estou desenvolvendo uma app que recebe notificações vindas do firebase, eu estou conseguindo receber as notificações tranquilamente quando a aplicação esta aberta, tudo que eu instanciei no NotificationCompat funciona, porem quando a aplicação se encontra em background nada funciona, a mensagem é exibida com titulo e conteúdo, mas o ícone e os sons nao são chamados. Alguém poderia me ajudar.

### Classe pra receber a mensagem

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {


private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseMsgService";

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {


    Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());

   if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData());
    }

   if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Message Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
    }



    notifyuer(remoteMessage.getFrom(), remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
    // Also if you intend on generating your own notifications as a result of a received FCM
    // message, here is where that should be initiated. See sendNotification method below.
}

public void notifyuer(String from, String notification){
    MyNotificationManager myNotificationManager = new MyNotificationManager(getApplicationContext());
    myNotificationManager.showNotificacao(from,notification, new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class));

 }
```

### Classe da notificação personalizada

```
public class MyNotificationManager {
private Context context;

public MyNotificationManager(Context context){
    this.context = context;
}

public void showNotificacao(String from, String notification, Intent intent){
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);



    //long[] vibrar = {150,400,150,800};


    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);

           Notification mNotification = notificationBuilder
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logocinza64)
            .setContentTitle("S.I.C.C.")
            .setContentText(notification)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setVibrate(new long[]{ 100, 250, 100, 500, 800})
            .build();

    mNotification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;


    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    try{
        Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        Ringtone toque = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(context,defaultSoundUri);
        toque.play();

    }catch (Exception e){

    }

    notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, mNotification);
 }

}
```